# Stub Devise 'current_user' method in Rspec without loading Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having trouble decoupling my tests from Rails.  For instance, how to stub the `current_user` method (from Devise) that gets called in the helper below?

Helper module:

```
module UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper

  def socialmedia_name(account)
    name = current_user.send(account)['info']['name']
    name = current_user.name if name.blank?
    name
  end

end
```

Test

```
require_relative '../../app/helpers/users_omniauth_callbacks_helper.rb'

describe 'UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper' do
  include UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper

  describe '#socialmedia_name(account)' do
    it 'should return the users name listed by the social media provider when that name is provided' do

      #once I've done away spec_helper, this next line ain't gonna fly.
      helper.stub(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, facebook:  {"info"=>{"name"=>"Mark Zuckerberg"}}) }

      socialmedia_name('facebook').should == "Mark Zuckerberg"
    end
  end
end
```

How do I stub the `current_user` method that gets used in the class?

If I were loading Rails, the test could still keep my `helper.stub(:current_user)`.  But naturally, that won't work now since I'm not loading the spec_helper file.

Comment: Extract your answer into an actual answer, not as the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing modules, your best choice is to include your helper into a test class, create a new instance, and then stub the methods from there. In addtion, you should move more of the name logic into the model, so that you don't need to have the helper know about `send(account)`, and that the return of it is a hash, which has a hash (Law of Demeter). I would want pretty much all of the socialmedia_name method to be in the model. For example:

```
describe 'UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper' do
  let(:helper) do
    Class.new do
      include UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper
      attr_accessor :current_user
    end.new
  end
  let(:user) { stub('user') }

  before do
    helper.current_user = user
  end

  describe '#socialmedia_name(account)' do
    it 'should return the users name listed by the social media provider when that name is provided' do
      # stub user here

      helper.socialmedia_name('facebook').should == "Mark Zuckerberg"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  I would have never thought about making a test class.  Before I do the refactoring that you recommend, though, I'd like to get the module tests working--just so I can get the practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with (before refactoring the code per Jim's recommendation).  Most importantly, the test runs incredibly quickly.  This helper may change, but I'll be using this rails-less strategy in a lot more of my work.

```
#spec/helpers/users_omniauth_callbacks_helper_spec.rb

require_relative '../../app/helpers/users_omniauth_callbacks_helper.rb'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'

describe 'UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper' do
  let(:helper) do
    Class.new do
      include UsersOmniauthCallbacksHelper
      attr_accessor :current_user
    end.new
  end

  describe '#socialmedia_name(account)' do
    it 'should return the users name listed by the social media provider when that name is provided' do
      helper.current_user = stub("user", :facebook =>{"info"=>{"name"=>"Mark Zuckerberg"}}) 
      helper.socialmedia_name('facebook').should == "Mark Zuckerberg"
    end

    it 'should return the current users name when the social media data does not provide a name' do
     helper.current_user = stub("user", name: "Theodore Kisiel", facebook: {"info"=>{}}) 
      helper.socialmedia_name('facebook').should == "Theodore Kisiel"
    end
  end
end
```